# Scan Uploaded File For Virus Or Malware In Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, antivirus, antivirus-integration

I am looking for a solution where I want to scan uploaded files for any virus threat. To achieve this I am thinking of below approach.

1. Upload the files to a specific temporary location in the server.
2. Run virus scan using CLI and based the result If the file is clean I will move the file to it's permanent location

All this will happen using AJAX request instead of full submission.

I am looking for any Virus Scan service which is compatible with Asp.Net Mvc. After doing a google search I came across some of the services but what I learned I need to post the uploaded files to their servers for complete the scan but that is something I don't want. I am thinning of now to use the installed AV from the server only

If anybody has achieved this kind of requirement previously requesting your suggestions on this

Comment: Why are you looking for a virus scanner "compatible with ASP.NET"? You're just dealing with files, it's not specific to the web framework you use.

Comment: Yes .. I mean I should be able to run the virus scanner from my asp.net mvc code. Ex : When the files gets uploaded to my temp location, I wanted to trigger the scanner and get a response back from it once it completes the scan.

Comment: That doesn't require "ASP.NET compatibility". Windows has an API to run a virus scan, or perhaps your particular virus scanner can be configured for a drop folder, or whatever. Don't limit your searches to "ASP.NET compatible virus scanners".